# Database Connectivity with oracle database using c#

Tags: c#, oracle

While trying to connect the oracle database I am getting the following error

**"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"}** 
Problem may be silly one but this is my first time with database so need help:

My code is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)

     {
         using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())

        {
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=ORCL_BOA; database=BOANEWDOC;User Id=BOANEWDOC;Password=BOANEWDOC;Trusted_Connection=true";
            conn.Open();
           //code

        }
```

Comment: try to use OracleConnection instead of SqlConnection.

Comment: ok sir going to try that too

Comment: Thanx a lot . It did work :)

Answer (score 0):

you may need to reference Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll on ODTwithODAC121012.zip you can download from oracle site.
do not use System.Data.OracleClient as it is obsolete.

```
            var connection = new OracleConnection(YourConnectionString);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
//AMK: Do some stuff with the db


            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
//AMK: do some other stuff in case of error

            }
            finally
            {
if(connection !=null && connection.State==ConnectionState.Open)               
  connection.Close();
            }
```